# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() youtube2mp3

Tags: java, servlets, runtime.exec, raspberry-pi, youtube-dl

I am working on a Java project for my Raspberry Pi and need help getting Runtime to work correctly.

youtube2mp3 uses youtube-dl and ffmpeg (INFO: http://jeffreyv.hubpages.com/hub/Youtube-to-MP3-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

I modified the script a bit while writing the code on my iMac :

```
x=youtube-dl-$RANDOM-$RANDOM.flv
youtube-dl --output=$x --format=18 "$1"
ffmpeg -i $x -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 128k -vn -y "$2"
mv "$2" ~/Downloads
rm $x
rm *.mp4
```

Then I tired to call it in my servlet to start a download:

```
try {
        String command = "sudo /usr/local/bin/youtube2mp3 \"" + requestedSong.getTrackUrl() +"\" \"" + requestedSong.getTrackArtist() + "-" + requestedSong.getTrackTitle() + ".mp3\"";
        System.out.println("CMD: " + command);
        //Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[]{"/usr/local/bin/youtube2mp3", "\"" + requestedSong.getTrackUrl() + "\"", "\"" + requestedSong.getTrackArtist() + "-" + requestedSong.getTrackTitle() + ".mp3 \""});
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        child.waitFor();
        InputStream in = child.getInputStream();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)));
        String line = "";
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
          line = sc.nextLine();
           System.out.println("INFO: " + line);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ControlServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ControlServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

The command if pretty verbose when it run, but my scanner object does not pick up anything.  I tried leaving this code in the servlet and also using threads, but both times it failed.

The command does not need sudo to run and I have already changed to sudoers file to not require a password for admin's (I'm running an arp scan earlier in the program using Runtime())

I am able to copy and paste the rule into terminal that "command" outputs and it runs fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here is the output of running the youtube2mp3 command:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/youtube2mp3 "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_tbksFYhl4" "test-none.mp3"
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] X_tbksFYhl4: Downloading video webpage
[youtube] X_tbksFYhl4: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] X_tbksFYhl4: Extracting video information
[download] Destination: youtube-dl-7433-2196.flv
[download] 100.0% of 39.17M at    1.83M/s ETA 00:00
ffmpeg version 0.11.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
built on Sep  6 2012 13:52:52 with clang 4.0 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60))
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.11.1 --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --cc=cc --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100
libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'youtube-dl-7433-2196.flv':
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
creation_time   : 2010-01-17 00:16:32
Duration: 00:09:59.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 548 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 113 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2010-01-17 00:16:32
  handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x270 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 432 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2010-01-17 00:16:33
  handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
Output #0, mp3, to 'test-none.mp3':
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
TDEN            : 2010-01-17 00:16:32
TSSE            : Lavf54.6.100
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2010-01-17 00:16:32
  handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
Stream mapping:
 Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=    9364kB time=00:09:59.22 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:9363kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.006039%
rm: *.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why do you wait for the process to finish before attempting to read the standard output?

Comment: I wanted to make sure that I captured everything.  I did the same thing with my arp-scan to make sure I got all Mac Addresses and/or errors.  This should not cause an issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the Process class doc: *Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.*

You mentioned that you get a verbose output, so I would try moving the `child.waitFor();` to the end of the `try` block. You don't need to worry that you will lose anything. To the contrary, streaming data is very natural in the OS. I'm pretty sure the InputStream won't be closed until the process finishes anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It still did not help however.  I am still not even hitting the inside of that while loop. Nor can I find the output file anywhere on the computer.  Anything else to try?

Comment: So which line do you get stuck after exactly? Right after `Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`?

Comment: The servlet continues to run without throwing errors.  I just cant tell that the youtube2mp3 process is running since it does now show any of the output. So it is never really getting "stuck". I just cant tell why it is not running the command. I will update the question to show the output of the command when I run it in terminal.

Comment: I think I had a problem like this when trying to run scripts. Somehow a script doesn't count as a command. From the docs: The methods that create processes may not work well for special processes on certain native platforms, such as native windowing processes, daemon processes, Win16/DOS processes on Microsoft Windows, or *shell scripts*. You might have to run all of those script commands separately. You are only interested in the output from ffmpeg, right? So, it shouldn't be such a pain.

Comment: I really hope that is not the case.  Since each of those scripts holds quite a few commands. I tired to change it to just run /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N-qO3sPMjc" instead of the script I wrote and got the same results.  I dont see why this is the case since I had to download arp-scan onto my machine and it runs prefectly.

`String command = "sudo /usr/local/Cellar/arp-scan/1.8/bin/arp-scan --interface=en1 192.168.1.0/24 ";
            Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            child.waitFor();`

Executes and prints fine.

Comment: Tried the same directory as arp scan since they were both downloaded with homebrew. /usr/local/Cellar/youtube-dl/2012.02.27/bin/youtube-dl with no luck either

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work.  Had to use a String array with "/bin/sh"

```
try {
        String outputInput = requestedSong.getTrackArtist() + "-" + requestedSong.getTrackTitle() + ".flv";
        String cmd1 = "sudo /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl --output=\"" + outputInput +"\" --format=18 \"" + requestedSong.getTrackUrl() +"\"";
        String cmd2 = "sudo /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i \"" + outputInput +"\" -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 128k -vn -y \"" + requestedSong.getTrackArtist() + " - " + requestedSong.getTrackTitle() +".mp3\"";
        String cmd3 = "mv \"" + requestedSong.getTrackArtist() + " - " + requestedSong.getTrackTitle() +".mp3\" ~/Downloads";
        String cmd4 = "rm -f outputInput";

        String[] cmdList = {cmd1, cmd2, cmd3, cmd4};

        for(int i = 0; i < cmdList.length; i++)
        {
            String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", cmdList[i]};
            System.out.println("CMD: " + cmdList[i]);
            Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            InputStream in = child.getInputStream();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)));
            String line = "";
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
            {
                line = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("INFO: " + line);
            }
            child.waitFor();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ControlServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ControlServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }



    }
```

Comment: Visit the Java World article linked from the [`exec` info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info).  There are still problems with that code.

Comment: Well it downloads and does everything I need it to.